# Why is the movie named 'Velvet Buzzsaw'?

Tags: title, velvet-buzzsaw

The movie [Velvet Buzzsaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velvet_Buzzsaw) is a 2019 supernatural horror film.

I found that in the film Rhodora Haze ([Rene Russo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rene_Russo)), owner of the Haze Gallery was a former member of the rock band *Velvet Buzzsaw*. She had a tattoo on her back which in the end killed her.

I didn't find any other reference to Velvet Buzzsaw, so why the movie is named 'Velvet Buzzsaw'?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the underlying theme. Velvet is soft. Buzzsaw is a tool used to cut through pretty hard materials. Good artists focus on creating good art, no matter which industry. The film shows us how people who represent artists and the ones creating the market aren't actually artists. In fact, many a time, they don't even know what they are doing.

- Morf is a critic who uses circumstances to make his decision on the
  artwork.
- Rhodora will do anything to increase the price of the art she owns.
- Jon Dondon is a complete art-noob.
- Gretchen too will do anything to increase the price of the art she
  owns.

These people aren't artists in the movie, yet are market makers.

The tool they have to influence the sell of an artist is a **soft** skill - reviews, personal relationship, networking, etc. But the effect of that is **deadly** (much like a buzzsaw) to the art and the artist.

One bad review sends Ricky into a coma. Or a 4 million deal on Hoboman is cancelled and is made to collect dust.

Comment: At first I thought you took the idea from [here](https://www.refinery29.com/en-us/2019/02/223204/what-does-velvet-buzzsaw-mean-netflix-title) (NSFW language usage warning), but then I read to the end, and looks like you either took only the first part, or didn't see that one at all. Anyway, good answer. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, thanks. Actually I'm an artist (music) and one of the names we worked for a band (a long time back) was an oxymoron too. Apparently it was a thing ;) 
Hadn't come across the refinery link before - an article dedicated just explain the name. woah.